# how to configure the "leak period" based on a custom measure

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I'm using sonarqube 6.2. We increment version number on every build, and sonarqube analyzes every build. 
Not every build goes into production environment, however.

I need to configure the leak period to compare the latest build against the latest version released in production (so not necessarily the previous version, or previous analysis, or "x" days...).

I thought I could create a custom measure (e.g. "is_released") to identify which version is in production, but then how do I configure the leak period to use this field (compare the current build against the latest version that "is_released")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't configure the *Leak Period* based on a custom measure.

At this stage I'd suggest using the [SonarQube Web API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API). Get the info (from your external systems) about which versions are released in prod' for project *foo* and set it accordingly in SonarQube (e.g. with *api/properties*):

> curl -u admin:admin -X POST "http://your_sonar_host/api/properties?resource=foo&id=sonar.timemachine.period1&value=v1.5.2"

Note: *api/properties* is about to be replaced by *api/settings* in upcoming SonarQube v6.3 .